# Do HBase coprocessors provide any atomicity across tables?

Tags: hbase

I am experimenting with HBase coprocessors for creating secondary indexing. It seems to be working. I am wondering if this approach provides any degree of atomicity.

Here is some sample code. It observes `Put`s on `tableA` and creates an inverted index in `tableB`:

```
public class MyObserver extends BaseRegionObserver {                                                                                                                                     

    public static final TableName TABLE_A = TableName.valueOf("tableA");                                                                                                            
    public static final TableName TABLE_B = TableName.valueOf("tableB");

    public static final byte[] family = Bytes.toBytes("f");                                                                                                                       
    public static final byte[] qualA = Bytes.toBytes("qualA");                                                                                                       
    public static final byte[] qualB = Bytes.toBytes("qualB");                                                                                                                 

    private Connection connection;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                     
    public void start(CoprocessorEnvironment env) throws IOException {                                                                                                            
        Configuration config = env.getConfiguration();                                                                                                                            
        connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                             

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                     
    public void stop(CoprocessorEnvironment env) throws IOException {                                                                                                             
        connection.close();                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                             

    @Override                                                                                                                                                                     
    public void prePut(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> env, Put put, WALEdit edit, Durability durability) throws IOException {                                      
        TableName tableName = env.getEnvironment().getRegionInfo().getTable();                                                                                                                                                                          

        if (!tableName.equals(TABLE_A)) {                                                                                                                          
            return;                                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                         

        byte[] key = put.getRow();                                                                                                                                             
        byte[] value = CellUtil.cloneValue(put.get(family, qualA).get(0));                                                                                             

        Put putB = new Put(value);                                                                                                                                          
        putB.addColumn(family, qualB, key);                                                                                                                         

        try (Table tableB = connection.getTable(TABLE_B)) {                                                                                                                        
            tableB.put(putB);                                                                                                                                               
        }                                                                                                                                                                         
        catch (IOException e) {                                                                                                                                                   
            logger.info("Error: {}", e);                                                                                                                                          
        }
    }                                                        
}
```

I am wondering though:

- Does the `Put` to `tableB` above get persisted if the subsequent `Put` to `tableA` fails?
- Conversely, if I change the hook above to `postPut()` and then the result of this hook fails, does the original `Put` that triggered `postPut()` still succeed?

Comment: Why are you trying to build your own Secondary indexing in HBase? Have you looked at variety of secondary index Phoenix(http://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html) provides? It will save you time and effort.

Comment: @AnilGupta I have, definitely. Motivation was two-fold: (i) didn't want the SQL layer from Phoenix. Only wanted this one specific thing. (ii) wanted to explore the coprocessor API. I've looked at other indexing/transaction projects. Have you tried any except Phoenix?

Comment: No, i havent tried. But, you can give others also a spin(trafodion, splice machine, tephra). However, i think most libraries on top of HBase is a sql layer. Seems like users want "SQL" in nosql.

Comment: Since you are trying to do coprocessors and build you own secondary index. You will get better help on this topic in hbase user mailing list. All the commiters reply there.

Comment: Oh thanks I will take a look at it. Good to know it's an active list.

Answer (score 1):

The index Put is being inserted with a different row key and as such these two mutations cannot be atomic. The obvious case is where index put is written to a completely different region server.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Put to tableB above get persisted if the subsequent Put to tableA fails?

The contract of `prePut` is that it applies its operations before the `Put` mutation operation occurs on the regionserver. Thus, if the `prePut` throws an exception, the callpath is interrupted and the request will never reach the regionserver mutate operation.

> Conversely, if I change the hook above to postPut() and then the result of this hook fails, does the original Put that triggered postPut() still succeed?

Yes, and conversely the contract for `postPut` is that it contains operations that are applied *after* the mutation is registered with the regionserver. If an exception is thrown from this implementation, it will surface to the caller, but the `Put` will have been registered with HBase at that point.